# Can't construct a query for the property, since the query selector wasn't defined

Tags: angular

Currently have this problem with a component in Angular 2 that exists of other components. The components of the 'main' component can exist multiple times in the hierarchy.

But i am getting this error:
**"Can't construct a query for the property "navComponent" of "SidenavLinkComponent" since the query selector wasn't defined"**

```
SidenavLinkComponent:
@ContentChild(SidenavNavComponent) navComponent: SidenavNavComponent;

SidenavNavComponent:
@ContentChildren(SidenavLinkComponent) linkComponents: QueryList<SidenavLinkComponent>;
```

I have made this slim plunker, where the problem is shown:
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Dnpmv6X2IO3WGQAg0372?p=preview)

I have no idea why it happens.

Comment: I guess it's because of the circular dependency. If you change the selector to a template variable its working https://plnkr.co/edit/mWIUi4fT5dby1C7Lx4RZ?p=preview

Comment: I had an issue where the placement of a file (containing a directive) in the project directory structure caused this error if the file wasn't above all of the consumers, even when they imported from a common module.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It's because of a circular dependency between `SidenavComponent` and `SidenavNavComponent`. It can be resolved using [forwardRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/forwardRef-function.html). Don't forget to import it as well:

```ts
import { forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
```

```ts
@ViewChild(forwardRef(() => SidenavNavComponent))
private navComponent: SidenavNavComponent;
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zWzlX1npWi2GKGnFsrWD?p=preview)

Comment: I have had the same problem. And this solution helped me. Thanks!

Comment: You should work for `Angular` team, You know so many black magic! ^_^

Comment: @Belter thanks. Spent a lot od time learning. Angular is fun :)

Comment: you are the savior. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be a circular dependency. Missing dependencies also cause this issue. e.x. `import { UndefinedService } from './somewhere'`

Comment: Hello there, i used forwardRef in code and it work well in my application, but I find when I am making a unit test for this component, this error show up, do you know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when using an enum in a specfile.

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mintplayer-ng-bootstrap-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ng-bootstrap-demo';
  colors = Color; // Comment out this line to make the unit tests succeed
}
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        // Component to test
        AppComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      // providers: [
      //   { provide: Color }
      // ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

enum Color {
  primary,
  secondary,
  success,
  danger,
  warning,
  info,
  light,
  dark,
  body,
  white,
  transparent
}
```

Don't know yet how to solve it, but I thought it might be interesting to point out since the error message is completely off...